# access tabulator component.getRow() from mutator when type !==edit: component.getRow is not a function

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using tabulator version 4.4.3

I have a use-case where I need to calculate cell values for each row depending data from different cell on different rows `row.getPrevRow()` with  `row.getNextRow()`
As follows:

```
function distanceMutator(value, data, type, params, component) {
  var row = component.getRow();
  var prevRow = row.getPrevRow();
  var nextRow = row.getNextRow();
  // Do not apply for first and last rows
  if (prevRow && nextRow) { 
    var nextdis = nextRow.getData().distance;
    var prevdis = prevRow.getData().distance;
    // Do the math 
    // ... yada yada
  return result; 
}
```

This does work if I am using `type=== "edit"`, when component is a cell but not when initial data is set with `setData();` where component is ColumnComponent.

My question is: 
Is there a convenient way to access current rows (and its previous and next rows as well) from ColumnComponent ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to try an navigate through row components inside a mutator

The mutator is called on the data as the row component is being built, one row at a time, so there are not an row components to navigate to when the table is being initiated.

At that point it may be easier to find the index of the row data object in the original array using ***findIndex*** on the array and then increment it to find the next rows data